# Workbench Data Updates

Tags: data, workbench

I am attempting to update some records in my org using Workbench which i do very often. Today when i go in and select account, and upload my csv, i keep getting the following error. This is a small file and only updating a few records, and i perform much larger uploads than this regulary. With that being said i am sure it is not the file size. Is there anything going on with Workbench that is causing this error? Thank you!

Workbench almost exhausted all its memory after only processing 0 rows of data.
When performing a large data load, it is recommended to use a zipped request for processing with the Bulk API.
To do so, rename your CSV file to 'request.txt', zip it, and try uploading again to Workbench.

Comment: Workbench has been going through it the past few weeks, maybe use data loader for data updates for now?

Comment: Welcome users finding this question via search. **Please do not post "I'm having this problem too", and do not open new questions about this issue**. The SFSE community cannot troubleshoot service-level issues with Workbench. Please post an answer if you discover a workaround for this issue.